# How can I cange how a Property is diplayed in a GridDataViewer

Tags: c#

The situation is this:

I have a `Form` which contains a `DataGridView`. That `DataGridView` is binded to an object `BindingSource`.
The objects binded have a `Property` which is an enum.

What I want to do is to put a column in the `DataGridView` but instead of showing the number of the enum, I want to map it to a `String`

Is there an easy way of doing this?

I am thinking of adding another `Property` to the model that returns the `String` I want to show, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Edit:

The `enum` is this:

```
public enum FilterClass
{
    TypeAFilter = 1,
    TypeBFilter = 2,
    TypeCFilter = 3
};
```

I am quite new to the C# world, so maybe I am doing something completely wrong

Comment: can you show what the enum definition looks like..? also are you wanting to convert the enum into it's string representation..?

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924257/how-to-display-enum-values-in-datagridview-column

Comment: @platon I don't have a `DataTable`, I have a list of objects binded to the BindingSource

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have edited the question and put the enum there. Maybe there's something I need to know about enums to make that in better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new field in the BusinessObject class which represents the string representation of an enum and bind the DataGridView's Column to this property.  Does this approach meet your requirements?

```
public string EnumString {
  get { 
    FilterClass fClass = this.FilterClass;
    return fClasss.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Basically, you mean adding a new Property to the object I'm displaying that makes the conversion to the string.

Comment: Yes, this should be easy to implemented. I will post the code shortly in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to get the name of each of the Enums in String Representation

for example in your class do something like this

this is just an example of where you would put the Enum Declaration Please let me know if this is what you are wanting other wise I will have to change my Answer

```
namespace sampleLogin
{
    public enum FilterClass
    {
        TypeAFilter = 1,
        TypeBFilter = 2,
        TypeCFilter = 3
    };

    public partial class frmLogin : Form
    {
      public frmLogin()
      {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (FilterClass fltClass in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FilterClass)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fltClass.ToString());
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What I want is if there is any easy way of converting the enum to a string but when it is displayed in the DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine that you **could not change the business object** (let's assume it was a 3rd party component), you could simple create a custom column:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // filling up example data
    var s = new List<InfoItem>();
    s.Add(new InfoItem() { PropertyA = "PA", PropertyB = 1, PropertyC = DateTime.Now, PropertyD = InfoItemType.Item_B });
    s.Add(new InfoItem() { PropertyA = "PB", PropertyB = 2, PropertyC = DateTime.Now, PropertyD = InfoItemType.Item_C });
    s.Add(new InfoItem() { PropertyA = "PC", PropertyB = 3, PropertyC = DateTime.Now, PropertyD = InfoItemType.Item_A });
    s.Add(new InfoItem() { PropertyA = "PD", PropertyB = 4, PropertyC = DateTime.Now, PropertyD = InfoItemType.Item_B });

    // assign my collection to the DataGrid
    dg.DataSource = s;

    // let's create one more column at the end
    var column = new DataGridViewColumn();
    column.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    column.HeaderText = "Custom Column";
    column.Name = "customColumn"; // important name to remember
    column.DataPropertyName = "PropertyD"; // the Enum Property
    dg.Columns.Add(column); // add the column
}

// let's make the use of the `CellFormatting` event
private void dg_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // If the column is the "customColumn", check the value. 
    if (this.dg.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "customColumn")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            // let's change to whatever we want...
            switch ((InfoItemType)e.Value)
            {
                case InfoItemType.Item_A: e.Value = "I'm A"; break;
                case InfoItemType.Item_B: e.Value = "I'm B"; break;
                case InfoItemType.Item_C: e.Value = "I'm C"; break;
                default: e.Value = "I'm not..."; break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

remember to attach the event to the `DataGridView` object as

[image]

then **the result** would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: I've seen this solution in another post. The guy was complaining that the execution of the `CellFormatting` event handler was delaying too much the application. Is that possible?

Comment: you would probably need to have hundreds of rows, witch I would never do, I would do a paging system for example, and there's always the chance that you can create your own custom `DataGridViewColumn`, witch I also did on my local example... I'm able to post that code if anyone wants...

Answer (score 0):

You can write an event handler for `DataGridView.CellFormatting`.  In the handler, the first parameter is the DataGridView (declared as object), and the second parameter is of type `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs` and it has a property `ColumnIndex`.  If the call is for the correct column index, then you can get the `row`, and `cell` from the `DataGridView`, and then format the cell any way you like.

There's also an even more complicated way, where you can assign event handlers to the column, but I won't repeat that here.  See my other postings if you're interested in this method.

So, it's probably simpler to just create another property on the object that is what you want to display.  But I've added this answer for completeness.